# How do you use environments that have the same name within a single LaTeX document?

Tags: trees, bussproofs, prooftrees

I'm trying to typeset some proof tree exercises. But I need to use the `prooftree` environment from the `bussproofs` package, as well as the `prooftree` environment from the `prooftrees` package. Is there a way I can rename one of these so that they are both usable within a single document?

Comment: Since these kind of environments are not used too often (at least I haven't see any) it would be nice from you to provide a minimal non working example with code for both and let as try to do the job needed just for your request and not all the search needed from someone that doesn't use these packages...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As explained in the `prooftrees` documentation, you can use the environment `tableau` instead of  `prooftree` if you load the `prooftrees` package with the `tableaux` option. This allows you to use both `bussproofs` and `prooftrees` together.

```
\usepackage[tableaux]{prooftrees}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
```

Here's a full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tableaux]{prooftrees}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}


\begin{prooftree}
   \AxiomC{$A \lor B$}
       \AxiomC{[$A$]}
       \noLine
       \UnaryInfC{$C$}
             \AxiomC{[$B$]}
              \noLine
              \UnaryInfC{$C$}
        \TrinaryInfC{$C$}
\end{prooftree}
\begin{tableau}
{
     to prove=\neg(a \vee b) \vee ((a \vee b) \vee  b)
}
[{(a \vee b) \vee ((a \vee b) \vee  b)}, just = 1
    [{\neg (a \vee b)}, just = 2
        [{a,b},just=3,close={4}
        ]
    ]
    [{(a \vee b) \vee  b}
        [{a \vee b}
        ]
        [{b}
        ]
    ]
]
\end{tableau}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: When I try to compile this, I get the following error: File `forest-lib-tableaux.sty' not found. This file doesn't appear to be in either the forest package or the prooftrees package. Do you know how to resolve that error?

Comment: Is your distribution up to date? This is part of `prooftrees`.

Comment: @objectivesea - Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when did you last update it and all LaTeX packages? The current version of `prooftrees` is v. 0.6, dated 2017/02/09. The `bussproof` package was last updated in 2011.

Comment: Updating MacTeX resolved the issue.

Comment: If you load `bussproofs` first, you don't even need the package option.

Comment: @cfr Hi, welcome back. We've missed you around here!

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank the L3 team for their bug ;). Thank you. I appreciate your comment. I've sent a new version of prooftrees to CTAN which I think fixes a couple of bugs identified here.